# What does the set -x command do in LabTalk Origin2015

Tags: plot, set, originlab

I have to maintain an old program that uses a LabTalk script to draw some charts. This script that does not run correctly. Since I am a total beginner with Origin Labtalk I have the following question:
My code opens 2 data-sources and is supposed to draw the data into 1 graph. 
When I execute my code it opens an empty graph.

```
%A=C:\A_Grid#2a.dat;
%B=C:\A_Grid#2b.dat;   
xn= 41;
...
window -a Data1;
for (i=1;i<=xn;i+=1) {
   worksheet -t $(i*2-1) 4;
   worksheet -n $(i*2) B$(i);
   worksheet -n $(i*2-1) A$(i);
}
window -i;
window -a Data2;
for (i=1;i<=yn;i+=1) {
   worksheet -t $(i*2-1) 4;
   worksheet -n $(i*2) B$(i);
   worksheet -n $(i*2-1) A$(i);
}
window -i;
window -a Plot;
for (i=1;i<=xn;i+=1) {
   %k=Data1_B$(i);
   set %k -x Data1_A$(i);     // without these lines it works but Why?
   layer -i %k;
}

for (i=1;i<=yn;i+=1) {
   %k=Data2_B$(i);
   set %k -x Data2_A$(i);    // without these lines it works but Why?
   layer -i %k;
}
```

When I leave out the following lines, it works.

```
set %k -x Data1_A$(i);
```

.

```
set %k -x Data2_A$(i);
```

Does anybody know

1. what this line is supposed to do?
2. What the set-command is?
3. What -x means ?

Thanks for your help.

itelly

Answer (score 0):

In your example the command sets the values of `Data1_A1`, `Data1_A2`, etc. as X values for the Y value datasets `Data_B1`, `Data_B2`, etc.

> -x value; Associate an X dataset with a Y dataset
>
> Syntax: set -x value
>
> Associate an X dataset with a Y dataset. Value must be a dataset name
>   and serves as the X values for the dataset name. A graph window must
>   be the active window. Value can refer to any dataset.

More information about the set command can be found [here](http://www.originlab.com/doc/LabTalk/ref/Set-cmd).